# Use final constant inside an enum

Tags: java, constants

I wanted to know what is the best way to use a final variable inside an enum?, I tried that but i get the following error: Illegal forward reference.

```
enum KeyTypes {

    BOLSA(NONE), // Illegal forward reference

    LLAVE(NONE), // Illegal forward reference

    MAGIC("net.labs.key.magical");

    private static final String NONE = "";

    private final String keyClass;

    KeyTypes(String keyClass).....

}
```

Comment: You can define constants in a separate static class file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this :

```
enum KeyTypes {

    BOLSA(), // default constructor

    LLAVE(), // default constructor

    MAGIC("net.labs.key.magical");

    private static final String NONE = "";

    private final String keyClass;

    KeyTypes() {
        this(NONE);
    } 

    KeyTypes(String keyClass).....

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Assign the property with reference instead of direct property name:**

```
public enum KeyTypes {

    BOLSA(KeyTypes.NONE),   // assign value with reference here
    LLAVE(KeyTypes.NONE), 
    MAGIC("net.labs.key.magical");

    private static final String NONE = "";
    private final String keyClass;

    KeyTypes(String keyClass){
        this.keyClass=keyClass;
    }

}
```